# HashMap get or insert and return a reference from a function

Tags: rust, hashmap

I have the following code where I would like to return a reference from a HashMap (either get or insert a new value) and only do a single lookup. Is this possible in Rust?

[Here is a playground link to play around with.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8f6cde69fd06cdd337e1bf4b25f85512)

```
fn get(key: u32, map: &mut HashMap<u32, String>) -> &mut String {
    match map.entry(key) {
        Entry::Occupied(mut entry) => entry.get_mut(),
        Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
            entry.insert("Hello".into())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1a03dcd298445adf5523f00f40ab009f)?

```
fn get(key: u32, map: &mut HashMap<u32, String>) -> &mut String {
    map.entry(key).or_insert_with(|| "Hello".into())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code using `Entry::get_mut()` doesn't compile because `get_mut()` returns a lifetime associated with the entry. You need to use `Entry::into_mut()` instead, which consumes the entry and returns a reference connected to the `HashMap`:

```
fn get(key: u32, map: &mut HashMap<u32, String>) -> &mut String {
    match map.entry(key) {
        Entry::Occupied(entry) => entry.into_mut(),
        Entry::Vacant(entry) => entry.insert("Hello".into()),
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6c814fb5d47330ea47b7ee73be990302)

Or, as the other answer says, you can use `or_insert_with()`.

Comment: I missed the into_mut() function, thanks for the info!